# PHP's getimagesize() throwing "SSL: The specified procedure could not be found"

Tags: php, ssl, getimagesize

I'm getting the following error message using php's getimagesize on a small percentage (<5%) of image links tested...

> getimagesize(): SSL: The specified procedure could not be found.

Here's an example that's throwing the error (on both my local/MAMP server and live version)...

```
getimagesize("https://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/65858681.jpg");
```

Anyone have any ideas how to dig into this further?  Really don't know where to go with it and couldn't find many similar questions.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you execute `file_get_contents` on the faulty URLs?

Comment: ahh, nope - exactly the same error message - so nothing to do with getimagesize() but still not sure where to go with troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do the trick for you

```
 <?php
function getimgsize($url, $referer = '')
{
    $headers = array(
                    'Range: bytes=0-32768'
                    );

    /* Hint: you could extract the referer from the url */
    if (!empty($referer)) array_push($headers, 'Referer: '.$referer);

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $image = imagecreatefromstring($data);

    $return = array(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));

    imagedestroy($image);

    return $return;
}

list($width, $heigth) = getimgsize('https://cdn.meme.am/instances/500x/65858681.jpg', 'https://cdn.meme.am/instances/');

echo $width.' x '.$heigth;
?>
```

Comment: thanks Sumit - not sure I understand your code, but I now see this error message: "imagecreatefromstring(): Empty string or invalid image"

Comment: same issue - even with referer specified - are you seeing something different when running this yourself?

Comment: i run the same code and i am getting the width and height.

Comment: thanks Sumit - that's true but it's still erroring at the same place for me - guess that means it must be a server issue - any ideas what further steps I could take?  I'm marking this as a correct answer in the meantime since it did at least work outside my server!

Comment: check  whether curl is install or not